# Server (os: Ubuntu) setup using gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I need some applications to be installed on Ubuntu machine. scenario is as below

1) Some applications are dependent on other application

2) If some applications are already installed then skip it and proceed further.

Please refer below sample gradle example,

1) install_b is dependent on install_a.

2) If install_a is already installed then how to skip task install_a in gradle.

```
task install_a(type: Exec) {
  executable "sh"
  args "-c","sudo apt-get install SOMEAPP"
}

task install_b(type: Exec) {
 dependsOn << install_a
 executable "sh"
 args "-c","sudo apt-get install ANOTHERAPP"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has a feature to [skip tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:skipping_tasks). You would write something like

```
task install_a(type: Exec) {
    ...
    onlyIf { file('/some/file/from/someapp').exists() }
}
```

You could also execute some command in the onlyIf closure if you'r not happy with checking for a single file.

Gradle also supports [up to date checks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api), but with those it will always execute the task the first time it's ran.